# Google MAP iOS Satellite view is too cloudy now

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have been working on one application since last one year which which make use of Google MAP iOS SDK. Application provide user with flexibility to switch between Satellite view and Normal view.  Everything was working fine till 2 days before, suddenly I observed tile images in case of Satellite view are too cloudy and Satellite view looks too bad now.

Our application is showing Satellite view of "st barthelemy" island. Below are the satellite view of Island which does not look good anymore and my client app sale is affected because of this ;(

New:
[image: New]

Old:
[image: Old]

I have following question:

- Is there way to request old version of google map tiles? Google Earth seems to have such flexibility where we can specify the tile db date.
- Does google map ios SDK support Network links? I have identified one other workaround to suppress this cloudy image by overriding with custom KML which make use of Network Links. But this Google MAP iOS SDK does not seems to support Network Links.
- How frequently google update their tile database? So that we wait for their next tile update ;(
- Is there direct forum where we can raise a concern for this?

Comment: That's actually the start of the new ice age. :/

Comment: Off-topic: nice app :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but MapBox (https://www.mapbox.com) has really nice Satellite maps that don't have clouds.  They have an iOS SDK you can plug into your app.  I am not sure if that will work for you or not.  I use them for my app and I really like it.

Comment: Yes but we need to add support for Google MAPs. Mapbox is good and is based on Route Me which I was using before in the application. But now client requested to replace Route Me with Google Map. We can not use Google Map tile source with mapbox. So we left with the option to use cloudy satellite map!

Comment: Yes, I believe you have to use Google Maps then and as far as I know you will be stuck with cloudy maps.